# sudo cat << EOF > File doesn't work, sudo su does

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

I tried the following on the command prompt in bash:

```
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/some-name.repo
#Content
#....
#...
EOF
```

It complained :

```
-bash: /etc/yum.repos.d/some-name.repo: Permission denied
```

Then I did `sudo su` and tried the exact same thing except the `sudo` before `cat`, and it worked without any problem. What am I missing in the above ?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Output redirection (e.g., >) is performed by bash, not by cat, while running with your UID. To run with root's UID use sudo:

```
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/some-name.repo
line1
line2
line3
EOF'
```

Comment: The part I don't understand is that I am already using a bash prompt, then why I need a`bash -c`.

Comment: Because in this case redirection will be performed by bash started with "root" uid that have enough rights to write to /etc/yum.repos.d/.

Comment: You can use any other utility that redirect output. For example "cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/some-name.repo"

Answer (score 78):

Another option is tee.

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/some-name.repo
...
EOF
```

Answer (score 43):

As a variation to @Yuriy Nazarov's answer, only the piped output needs to be elevated thru `sudo`. The piped input can stay un-elevated:

```
sudo bash -c 'cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/some-name.repo' << EOF
line1
line2
line3
EOF
```

This means a much smaller portion of the command needs to be quoted and sent thru to `sudo`.

Comment: This was a huge improvement over the accepted answer in my case, since my piped output was full of variables and shebangs and stuff.

Comment: I like how clean it is compared to the official answer.

Answer (score 12):

As others have pointed out the shell redirection is done by the current shell not by cat.  sudo only changes the permission of the program that is executed not of the shell doing the redirect.  My solution to this is to avoid the redirect:

```
sudo dd of=/etc/yum.repos.d/some-name.repo << EOF
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are using ' inside the text then you may use:

```
$ sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf << EOF
user = mail_admin
password = password
dbname = mail
query = SELECT destination FROM forwardings WHERE source='%s'
hosts = 127.0.0.1
EOF
"
```

this is tested on google cloud's virtual server centos 7.0